# Why does my -p one-liner print the lines I'm trying to skip?

Tags: perl

I have a file named file with three lines:

> line one
>   line two
>   line three

When I do this:

> perl -ne 'print if /one/' file

I get this output:

> line one

when i try this:

> perl -pe 'next unless /one/' file

the output is:

> line one
>   line two
>   line tree

I expected the same output with both one-liner. Are my expectations wrong or is wrong something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong.  The [`-p` switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-p) puts the following loop around your code:

```
LINE:
  while (<>) {
      ...             # your program goes here
  } continue {
      print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
  }
```

If you read [the documentation for `next`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html), it says:

> Note that if there were a `continue`
> block on the above, it would get
> executed even on discarded lines.

`next` actually jumps to the [continue block](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html) (if any), before it goes back to the loop's condition.

You could do something like

```
perl -pe '$_ = "" unless /one/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

First about the options used in the programs:

```
-n    assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
-p    assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
```

.

```
perl -ne 'print if /one/' file
```

prints only the first line as its the only line having the string "one" in it.

```
perl -ne 'next unless /one/' file
```

will not print anything because it has no call to print and no `-p` option.

```
perl -pe 'next unless /one/' file
```

Almost same as above there is no output from the program itself but because of the `-p` option, every line of the file is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -ne 'next unless /one/ && print' file
line one
```